# (Conceptual) AJAX GET Request vs HTTP GET Request: who is technically the client?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, client-server

So when a normal `GET` request is done via the browser I'd argue that the browser is the client. But who is the client when a `GET` request via AJAX? I know it is still happening via the browser, but I'd like to see if I can get a more granular view of it.

Could you say that the javascript engine of the browser is the client for an AJAX `GET` request and for a general `GET` request, then the browser as a whole is a client? I'd argue that you could say that provided that the javascript engine of a browser runs in a different process.

Who could shed some light on this?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) says on AJAX:

> XMLHttpRequest (XHR) is an API in the form of an object whose methods
>   transfer data between a web browser and a web server. The object is
>   provided by the browser's JavaScript environment.

Comment: It's just the same things. Basically in two words the difference is that normal request refreshing the page while ajax not

Comment: You *could* say a lot of things. But the browser makes the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's put it in a broader scenario: Browser/web-server communication follow a [Client–server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model). From the server point-of-view, the client is an IP address+IP port that has started a [http request](http://rve.org.uk/dumprequest).

The answer to the http request will be sent back to the originating IP address+IP Port, where the originating process will manage it.

**This process is your browser. It will accept the answer an internally manage it.**

Browsers can start client requests for several types of protocols. Typically *HTTP* or *HTTPS*, but also *FTP*, *FILE*...

`XMLHttpRequest` is 'just' an API, internally supported by current browsers that...

> ...provides client functionality for transferring data between a client and a server.
>
> [...] it can can be used to retrieve any type of data, not just XML, and it supports protocols other than *HTTP* (including *FILE* and *FTP*).

More about `XMLHttpRequest` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

So, IMHO **the browser is the client for any kind of request (*HTTP* `GET`, *HTTP* `POST`...)**, no matter it has been initiated via Ajax/`XMLHttpRequest` or via a direct access to a URL. How internally the browser decides to manage it, is not conceptually related to Client/Server model.

Comment: Ok that seems reasonable. Why do my dev tools say it was an xhr request and not a GET request? I know an xhr request is not an HTTP verb, but my Chrome dev tools do give me the idea that they are.

Comment: @MelvinRoest  My browser says it's an XHR request but still tells me what type.